# HTML5 canvas context doesn't clear with clearRect()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvases: a buffer and a display canvas whose context gets a drawImage() call with the buffer canvas. I clearRect() both canvases before adding new objects and calling drawImage(), but both display all previously-added objects. This is the object-adding code (check out the full JSFiddle below):

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
buf.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
img.src = bufCanvas.toDataURL();
buf.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + ~~(Math.random()*360) + ', 100%, 70%)';
buf.rect(Math.random()*w, Math.random()*h, 20, 20);
buf.fill();
ctx.drawImage(bufCanvas, 0, 0);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3movoayv/10/

The top is the buffer (click your mouse there to generate new rects), the middle is the display canvas that I copy the buffer to, and the bottom is an img element that displays the contents of the buffer canvas after I call clearRect() (which always correctly displays nothing).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to begin a new path each time using [`.beginPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (prevents the event stacking issue you're witnessing):

```
bufCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  buf.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  img.src = bufCanvas.toDataURL();
  buf.beginPath(); // < begin a new path
  buf.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + ~~(Math.random()*360) + ', 100%, 70%)';
  buf.rect(Math.random()*w, Math.random()*h, 20, 20);
  buf.fill();
  ctx.drawImage(bufCanvas, 0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought you only had to begin/close paths when drawing lines.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but `closePath()` is not necessary when using `fill()` as `fill()` will close it internally (temporary). And in any case, there is no point calling `closePath()` *after* `fill()`. Just my 2 cents.